# fatal error: 'charconv' file not found in clang 6.0 with -std=c++17

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17, clang++

Recently, I wanted to use `from_chars` from c++17.
Looked at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars and found that code on this page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> str{"42"};
    int result;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), result);
    std::cout << result;
}
```

cannot be compiled by any of compilers. I tried on page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars and on godbolt with different compilers but all of them returned the same error:

```
<source>:2:10: fatal error: 'charconv' file not found
#include <charconv>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Can anybody help me with this, please?

(I tried clang 6.0, gcc 7.3 and msvc 19 but all of them returned error that 'charconv' not found)

Comment: charconv is a new file added to libstdc++ 
 on 2 Oct 2017, as shown in https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2017-10/msg00001.html. you need to update your libstdc++ firstly.

Comment: @gzh do you know if MSVC supports it in last releases?

Comment: I do not whether MSVC supports it or not, I think you need check its release note.

Comment: please see this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/

Answer (score 6):

According to [GCC's libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html), this header is only supported starting from GCC-8.1. You could either avoid using this header by detecting it:

```cpp
#if __has_include(<charconv>)
#include <charconv>
#else
/* implement some fallback */
#endif
```

Or just update your compiler. This [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/TqGPb6) confirms that the header is present in GCC-8.1.

If you use Clang, remember that Clang uses GCC's `stdlibc++` by default. You will either need to update your GCC or switch to Clang's `libc++` by:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp
```

Comment: I tried using both `g++` and `clang++` after getting them both updated. `g++` is 8.4 and `clang++` is 10.0. I tried with `-stdlib=stdlibc++`, `stdlib=libc++` and nothing just in case. Then I enabled backports and pre-release and tried again. (I made sure `g++`, `/usr/bin/g++`, etc. pointed to the new versions.) I don't know what's left. Every time I switch to `libc++` it stops finding anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

update `gcc` version to `8.3`, seems like an older gcc version causing problems